# Is it possible to reload or reset an array in as3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, reload, reset, restore

I'm wondering if it is possible to reset / reload / reconstruct an array order?

I'm making this "Space Invaders" game and the enemy's need to restart to it's position when the game is being restarted. When I shoot down the enemy's and reset my game, the enemy's I've killed keep being gone.

So here's some of the code responsible:

```
var spiderArray:Array = new Array(enemyField.enemy1,enemyField.enemy2,
                             enemyField.enemy3,enemyField.enemy4,
                             enemyField.enemy5,enemyField.enemy6,
                             enemyField.enemy7,enemyField.enemy8,
                             enemyField.enemy9,enemyField.enemy10,
                             enemyField.enemy11,enemyField.enemy12,
                             enemyField.enemy13,enemyField.enemy14,
                             enemyField.enemy15,enemyField.enemy16,
                             enemyField.enemy17,enemyField.enemy18,
                             enemyField.enemy19,enemyField.enemy20,
                             enemyField.enemy21,enemyField.enemy22,
                             enemyField.enemy23,enemyField.enemy24,
                             enemyField.enemy25,enemyField.enemy26,
                             enemyField.enemy27,enemyField.enemy28,
                             enemyField.enemy29,enemyField.enemy30,
                             enemyField.enemy31,enemyField.enemy32,
                             enemyField.enemy33,enemyField.enemy34,
                             enemyField.enemy35,enemyField.enemy36,
                             enemyField.enemy37,enemyField.enemy38,
                             enemyField.enemy39,enemyField.enemy40,
                             enemyField.enemy41,enemyField.enemy42,
                             enemyField.enemy43,enemyField.enemy44,
                             enemyField.enemy45,enemyField.enemy46,
                             enemyField.enemy47,enemyField.enemy48,
                             enemyField.enemy49,enemyField.enemy50,
                             enemyField.enemy51,enemyField.enemy52,
                             enemyField.enemy53,enemyField.enemy54,
                             enemyField.enemy55,enemyField.enemy56,
                             enemyField.enemy57,enemyField.enemy58,
                             enemyField.enemy59,enemyField.enemy60,
                             enemyField.enemy61,enemyField.enemy62,
                             enemyField.enemy63,enemyField.enemy64,
                             enemyField.enemy65,enemyField.enemy66);
```

Now the place where the enemy's are being killed:

```
function enemyHitTest():void {
//for each of the three spiders
for(var i:int = 0; i < spiderArray.length; i++) {
    //the each of the six bullets
    for(var j:int = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        //don't consider bullets that aren't in play:
        if(bulletArray[j].y > SpelerMC.y) continue;
        if(spiderArray[i].hitTestObject(bulletArray[j])) {
            score += 10;
            scoreTxt.text = score.toString();
            trace("Invader " + i + " neergeschoten!");
            spiderArray[i].parent.removeChild(spiderArray[i]);
            bulletArray[j].x = j * 70 + 100;
            bulletArray[j].y = 595;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I think I need to put some sort of `theArray.pop();` or something, but don't know how to use it, but I need to place it in this function:

```
function startGame() {
trace("Start het spel opnieuw...");
gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
gameTimer.start();
enemyField.x = 400;
enemyField.y = 160;
SpelerMC.x = 83;
SpelerMC.y = 531;
}
```

Please help me! Have been searching for 5 hours already.
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove element number `i` use `array.splice(i, 1);` ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice().com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) but keep in mind that `array.length` will decrease
to reset the array just invoke `spidersArray = new Array(enemyField.enemy1, etc)` again

**UPDATE**
in in the `enemyHitTest` function i changed the removing condition to `if(enemyArray[i].visible && enemyArray[i].hitTestObject(laserArray[j]))` and `enemyArray[i].parent.removeChild(enemyArray[i]);` to `enemyArray[i].visible = false;` 
and added

```
function respawnEnemies():void{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < enemyArray.length; i++) {
        enemyArray[i].visible = true;
    }
}
```

to call it from `startGame`

full code [here](http://pastebin.com/YSg81d0F)

*upd 2*
so the problem was not in resetting the array but in the fact that your enemyField and its' enemies were added to stage manually and removed programmatically so there was no code to call to bring them back

Comment: I've tried the splice already, doesn't work.. the hittest is there, but the invader i hit doesn't go away. And the method u use for the Array reset i've tried also. When i run the startGame(); function with the array in it, it doesn't reset it.. :(

Comment: @user1744027 if you upload your project somewhere i'll try to fix it, missing the whole picture with given information

Comment: Thank you for making time helping me! Here's the file to download: http://www.frankgraave.nl/testbestand.zip Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1744027 could you please make it cs4 compatible?

Comment: Coming in a few moments, need to save it in a CS5 version to downgrade to CS4. I'll post the link here in about 10 minutes!

Comment: Here is the CS4 compatible version: http://www.frankgraave.nl/space_invaders_cs4.zip Have a look and thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, this indeed makes a lot more sense! The enemy's where placed bij an array and shot down programmatically, thank you for helping me understand. Thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

if all your instances should be preserved - e.g. you generate all actors at the beginning and later all of them are reused (at the new game) you can set an array of them and on each start game make a copy and remove "dead" enemies from the copied array

also better option is to use a vector e.g.

```
var enemies:Vector.<Enemy> = Vector.<Enemy>([]);//in brackets references to the instances of Enemy class
var inGame:Vector.<Enemy> = enemies.concat();
```

also 5hrs of research? please be patient and try harder,

best regards